# Mysql error: Subquery returns more than 1 row (but I want it to - I want to select a vector on each row)

Tags: mysql, sql

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have tables `users` and `interests`

### users

```
id | name
---------
1  | amy
2  | brian
3  | carole
```

### interests

```
uid | interest
--------------
1   | apples
3   | catfish
3   | cobwebs
3   | cryogenics
```

What I want to get back is output that looks something like

```
name  | interests
----------------
amy   | apples
brian | 
carole| catfish, cobwebs, cryogenics
```

Where interests could be a string consisting of the concatenation of all relevant values with some delimiter, or a vector of discrete values. I'm interested in dumping this to a file, rather than putting it in a table or doing any kind of further SQL stuff with it. Doing

```
SELECT name, (SELECT interest from interests where uid=id) as interests from users;
```

Is giving me the error I mentioned in the title. Is this just not possible in the SQL paradigm? I know I can dump a join of these tables to a file, and then aggregate the values I need using a python script or something, but this feels inelegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT name , group_concat(interest) as interests from interests 
 LEFT JOIN users on users.id = interests.uid 
 GROUP BY name
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39332/3)

update:

if you want spaces do this `group_concat(interest SEPARATOR ', ')`

Comment: +1 . . . But you should include `separate ', '` since the OP has spaces in the example.

Comment: you welcome ! :) as @GordonLinoff said if you want spaces between interest use `SEPARATOR ', '` i will update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name, i.interest
FROM users AS u, interests AS i
WHERE u.uid = i.id
```

Try a join instead, this might work.

You might be getting errors because of the ordering of your select and from statements, or do you need to have a comma after name. Like:

```
SELECT name, ( *then your select statement here ...* )
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it would give me one interest per row. I want all interests corresponding to a given name on a single row. (You're right about the comma though - fixed).